# Android Data Binding @BindingConversion failure for int to string

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

Ran into a mysterious problem when trying to make a @BindingConversion for int to string.
The following code **works for floats to strings**:

xml:

```
...
<variable
        name="myViewModel"
        type="... .SomeModel" />
...
<TextView
            style="@style/StyleStuff"
            android:text="@{myViewModel.number}" />
```

code:

```
public class SomeModel {
    public ObservableFloat number = new ObservableFloat();
}
```

and setting:

```
viewModel.number.set(3.14f);
```

---

But if I try the same thing for **ints to strings** I get a crash.

```
 public ObservableInt number = new ObservableInt();
```

with

```
viewModel.number.set(42);
```

I get the following:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ...myapplication, PID: 14311
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xfa0
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1123)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getText(ResourcesWrapper.java:52)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4816)
    at ...executeBindings(ActivityAdaptersBinding.java:336)
    at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding.executePendingBindings(ViewDataBinding.java:355)
```

---

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 240, accepted):

`android:text` with an `int` assumes that the `int` is a string resource ID. Use `android:text="@{Integer.toString(myViewModel.number)}"`.

<strike>You will also need to import the `Integer` class:</strike> (no longer needed)

Comment: Aha!  Thank you!

I would've thought data binding would check and convert the int before it hit the text view, but apparently not~

This means that we should be careful whenever using BindingConversion if the original type might be misinterpreted and used without hitting the converter.

Comment: @Dave: "I would've thought data binding would check and convert the int before it hit the text view" -- no, because for all data binding knows, you *are* giving it a string resource ID. "This means that we should be careful" -- yes. :-)

Comment: How would you do this if you wanted to create 2-way binding?

Comment: @InfernalRapture: Perhaps an `@InverseBindingAdapter`, though I haven't played with that yet.

Comment: @CommonsWare That was what I was looking for, after a few hours of messing around that was the trick of it.

Comment: It matters that the import is before anything else, like in my case were i had a variable in my data clause. Import types must be before the variable.

Comment: I dont think import is necessary. As java.lang.* are available by default

Comment: how its possible two way bindings?

Comment: @SreejeshKNair: `TextView` does not support input, so there is no need for a two-way binding with `TextView`.

Answer (score 28):

**Beware**, In latest `DataBinding` (2019), It does **NOT** require importing `Integer` nor `String`
or you will get this error:

```
****/ data binding error ****msg:Missing import expression although it is registered file
```

[official doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#imports) says : `java.lang.* is imported automatically.`

Just go either

`android:text="@{Integer.toString(myViewModel.number)}"` 
or

`android:text="@{String.valueOf(myViewModel.number)}"`

directly.

Comment: This is should be upvoted, today databinding doesn't need to import `java.lang.String` or `java.lang.Integer` in order to do the conversion.

Answer (score 23):

Convert int to string for set in TextView like below:

```
android:text="@{String.valueOf(myViewModel.number)}"
```

Also, `String` class must be imported by the layout:

```
<layout>
   <data>
      <import type="java.lang.String" />
   </data>

   …

</layout>
```

Answer (score 19):

#### Simplest solution, may be it would help someone.

```
android:text="@{`` + model.intValue}"
```

This can be used in [two-way binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way) for `EditText` also. Where users input is set as **Integer** value in model, and shown as `String`.

```
android:text="@={`` + model.intValue}"
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52314321/6891563) also.

Answer (score 7):

It's too late but i update it for newbies.
You can parse to int in xml by using:

```
Integer.parseInt(string)
```

or to String by:

```
String.valueOf(string)
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me

```
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:text='@={Converter.convertIntToString(myViewModel.number)}'

        />
```

Converter class with inverse method

```
public class Converter {


public static int convertStringToInt(String text) {
   return Integer.parseInt(text);
}

@InverseMethod(value="convertStringToInt")
public static String convertIntToString(int value) {
    return Integer.toString(value);
}}
```

Comment: This is overkill!

Comment: You can use Binding Adapter for this.