# Android make value from multiple EditTexts to a class?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-databinding

I am using data binding, I am trying to create a class with the values when the user fills up multiple edit texts, also with some validations.

the class is something like

```
data class Person(
    var name: String,
    var age: Int,
    var email: String
)
```

The view model variable,

```
val person: MutableLiveData<Person> by lazy { MutableLiveData<Person>()}
```

The template

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:text="@{viewModel.person.name}" />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="@{viewModel.person.age}" />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:text="@{viewModel.person.email}" />
```

with the click on button, I am trying to print out the object,

```
binding.savebtn.setOnClickListener {
    Log.d("debug", "${viewModel.person.value}:")
}
```

and it prints out `D/debug: null:`

I am trying to create a room entity after validation. How can I make this work?

Comment: This is what you are looking for, [Two way data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38982604/two-way-databinding-in-edittext)

Comment: Check out the answer below, I hope you will appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
val person: Person by lazy { Person("","","")}
```

and then in the `onclicklistener`

```
binding.savebtn.setOnClickListener {
    Log.d("debug", "${viewModel.person.name},${viewModel.person.email}")
}
```

You will get the values, but the issue is, when you change the value in model it wont be reflected in the `EditText`, since these are plain `String` objects not `livedata` or `ObservableField`.

Let's you do, `viewModel.person.name="custom name"` it wont change the text in `EditText`. **If you target to only get the typed text into the model directly, then this will do it for you.**