# Android two way binding with Integer type causes databinding does not exist

Tags: android, android-databinding

I'm having some issue with implementing two way binding with an Integer data type.

```
public class User {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;

    public User() {}

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
       this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
       return this.firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
       this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
       return this.lastName;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
       this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge() {
       return this.age;
    }

}
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data class="UserDataBinding">
        <variable
            name="user"
            type="com.databinding.model.User" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

       <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@={user.firstName}" />

       <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@={user.lastName}" />

       <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@={user.age}" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Unfortunately, it gives me the error

> "Error:(52, 17) Cannot find the getter for attribute 'android:text'
>   with value type java.lang.Integer on
>   android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText. "

If I change the attribute text to

```
       <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@={Integer.toString(user.age)}" />
```

then I get the error

> "Error:cannot generate view binders java.lang.NullPointerException"

Appreciate any help on this.

UPDATE: It seems there was another error right after the error mentioned above.

> cannot generate view binders java.lang.NullPointerException

Not sure why its giving me NPE even though the app hasn't started yet.

Comment: Maybe switching `Integer` to `int` might solve it because of automatic conversion from `String` to `int` or something. A hacky way would be to have the age stored as a String and then convert it.

Comment: Changed Integer to int in my User object but still getting the same error.

Comment: Try replacing the `Integer` with `ObservableInteger`. You will have to use the method `.set(SOMENUMBER)` then though. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37867988/android-data-binding-bindingconversion-failure-for-int-to-string) for reference. 
Dont forget to use the `Integer.toString()` method then

Answer (score 90):

Well, six months later but maybe i can help someone.

You can do this simple trick:

```
android:text="@={`` + mObject.someNumber}"
```

**OBS**.: You need at least **Android Studio 2.3**

Comment: I had to search hard to find this solution. It is by far the simplest and should be on top. Do you know where I can find documentation on this?

Comment: Sorry @xerotolerant

Like you, i didn't find any documentaion about this.

Comment: Does this work with, for example, double and int values at the same time?

Comment: Will this work for 2-way biniding? Will the typed string be converted into integer?

Comment: Great tip!  Thank you. Just in case some are like me, please note those symbols are back quotes (top left corner of your keyboard), not single quotes.

Comment: Note: this only works with primitive types, not e.g. BigDecimal.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, but as Hong just said, be aware that you can't use `'` or `"` inside the escaped code in XML, must use the backtick `

Comment: Undocumented, works only on some types, requires back-tick, fails for 2-way data-binding under these 7 conditions, resolved by writing `@BindingAdapters`, and/or custom converter methods or whole classes. Needs specific Studio version, new layout XML, `<variable>` or `<import>` nodes depending on `@jvmStatic`, data-binding compiler for Kotlin, `androidx` libraries...My GOD.  Android was already the worst SDK in history BEFORE google slapped a whole 'nuther SDK ON TOP of it.

Comment: For me, it did't allow clearing value and entering. Last digit remains in edit

Comment: Can you help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64596538/android-two-way-databinding-problem-of-ternary-operator-must-be-constant Thank you.

Answer (score 24):

`android:text="@{String.valueOf(Integer)}"`

Comment: This should be the accepted. Works perfectly and simple!

Comment: It wont allow editing. Question was about two way binding. It also should support "@={...}"

Answer (score 15):

Somehow I got this to work by using BindingAdapter and InverseBindingAdapter.

```
public class User {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;

    public User() {}

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
       this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
       return this.firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
       this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
       return this.lastName;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
       this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge() {
       return this.age;
    }

    @BindingAdapter("android:text")
    public static void setText(TextView view, int value) {
        view.setText(Integer.toString(value));
    }

    @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text")
    public static int getText(TextView view) {
        return Integer.parseInt(view.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will help someone else as well.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this solution but I still have a problem with it: every character that I type in the EditText reset the cursor at the beginning of the text. Do you experience the same issue? Any fix for this problem?

Comment: Ok, I've found a solution: set the new text only if the text of the `view` is different from the `value` in the `@BindingAdapter("android:text")`.

Answer (score 10):

I managed to use Integer.toString(...), doing the import, like this:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <import type="java.lang.Integer" />

        <variable ... />
    </data>
```

Answer (score 7):

The previous answer, along with Roberto Leinardi's comment worked perfectly for me!
I only have to add is that a null-check should be done to Roberto's check:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:text")
public static void setText(TextView view, int value) {
    view.setText(Integer.toString(value));
}

@BindingAdapter("android:text")
public static void setText(TextView view, int value) {
    if (view.getText() != null
            && ( !view.getText().toString().isEmpty() )
            && Integer.parseInt(view.getText().toString()) != value) {
        view.setText(Integer.toString(value));
    }
}
```

Comment: If you try to start writing negative number it will crash (you can't convert "-" to integer).

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution. It's clean and simple. Simply if layout needs String, give it a String instead of int. All you have to do is create a setter and getter with String type and use them to bind to ui while normal setter and getter doing the normal thing!

A complete code !

My POJO class(Mydata.java). `getAgeString` and `setAgeString` are the ui methods, doing the conversion. Note that I put `@Bindable` on `getAgeString`. so ui will use `ageString`

```
package com.databindingnumber;

import android.databinding.BaseObservable;
import android.databinding.Bindable;

public class MyData extends BaseObservable{
    private int age;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        if(this.age != age) {
            this.age = age;
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.ageString);//NOTE: ui is using ageString !
        }
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getAgeString() {
        return Integer.toString(age);
    }

    public void setAgeString(String ageString) {
        try {
            int val = Integer.parseInt(ageString);
            this.setAge(val);
        }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
            this.setAge(0);//default value
        }
    }
}
```

The Layout File(activity_main.xml). use normal two-way binding with `@=` but use `ageString` instead of `age`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable name="foo" type="com.databindingnumber.MyData"/>
    </data>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"
        android:text="@={foo.ageString}" />
</layout>
```

MainActivity.java file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        binding.setFoo(new MyData());
    }
}
```

Hope this will help to someone!

Answer (score 3):

The way of using @xdbas's solution

DataBindingConverter.kt

```
class DataBindingConverters {
    companion object {

        @InverseMethod("convertIntegerToString")
        @JvmStatic
        fun convertStringToInteger(value: String): Int? {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(value) || !TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(value)) {
                return null
            }
            return value.toIntOrNull()
        }

        @JvmStatic
        fun convertIntegerToString(value: Int?): String {
            return value?.toString() ?: ""
        }
    }
}
```

XML import

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <import type="com.package.DataBindingConverter" />
    </data>
.....
```

Bind to textView

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:text="@={DataBindingConverter.convertStringToInteger(ViewModel.user.age)}" />
```

Maybe I should have edited his answer but i don't know if it didn't work for him.

Answer (score 2):

This might help some people who need to get this to work with two way databinding and kotlin.

DataBindingConverter.kt

```
class DataBindingConverter {
    companion object {

        @InverseMethod("convertStringToInteger")
        @JvmStatic
        fun convertIntegerToString(value: String): Int? {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(value) || !TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(value)) {
                return null
            }

            return value.toIntOrNull()
        }

        @JvmStatic
        fun convertStringToInteger(value: Int?): String {
            return value?.toString() ?: ""
        }
    }
}
```

import that class in your view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <import type="com.package.DataBindingConverter" />
    </data>
.....
```

bind it to a textview

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:text="@={DataBindingConverter.convertStringToInteger(ViewModel.user.age)}" />
```

Comment: This is what I get please: `cannot find method convertIntegerToString(java.lang.Integer) in class com.package.DataBindingConverters`

Comment: DataBindingConverter.INSTANCE.convertStringToInteger(ViewModel.user.age)

Answer (score 0):

Add following in strings.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="_int">%d</string>
</resources>
```

Then you can do:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@{@string/_int(user.age)}" />
```